# Quick Suggestions not showing functions in VSCode JavaScript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Looking for a way to display functions in the quick suggestions in vscode. For example:

[image]
I cannot get str.replace() to appear in the suggested options.

I've explored the settings.json options but do not see anything there.

Comment: vscode has no way to know that `str` is a string.  Use a jsdoc comment to tell it that.

Comment: I am using `1.66.2` version of Visual Studio Code, IDE is suggesting possible suggestions/functions without installing any extension e.g, for string see  https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGfCW.png

Comment: @Garesh That is very different, because of your initialization of `str` to a string, the language server knows what type `str` is in your example.  That doesn't exist in the code shown in the question.